# Gmail API Get email via Postman

Tags: postman, gmail-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to call `Users.messages: get` api using POSTMAN:

```
Request type : GET
Request : https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/<my-email>/messages/<id>?key=<API-KEY>
Authorization : Bearer-token : <access_token received on successful login using Google>
```

What is the value of `id`?

What else is required to be added ?

Why does this return this error?

```
400. That’s an error. Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know.
```

Comment: What does the documentation say? https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

Answer (score 0):

The 400 error code means you are sending the request in the wrong way. I could guess it's because you are sending an ***id*** which doesn't exist, due to the fact you don't know what represents.

That ***id***, as the [docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#parameters) says, represents:

> The ID of the message to retrieve.

One easy way to retrieve the messages' id, it's using the [Users.messages: list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) endpoint and then you can try to retrieve that specific message using the [***Try this API***](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22email-id%22%7D)  tool.